# Group by and where by the same field, issue with nulls

Tags: sql

I have this table

```
    city counter
    A      1
    NULL   2
    A      1
    B      3

Query a: 
    select city, sum(counter)
    from my_table
    group by city 
    
Query b:
    select city, sum(counter)
    from my_table
    where ((city not like 'A') )  //filter A and NULL?
    group by city 
    
Query c:
    select city, sum(counter)
    from my_table
    where ((city not like 'A' or city is null) )
    group by city
```

When execute the query A, I have three grouped results: A, NULL and B, but when I execute the query b it filters A and NULL, why is NULL filtered? Do I have the query C to do this?

Comment: Yes,please use Query C

Comment: LIKE with no wildcard? I'd consider `city <> 'A'` instead.

Comment: What do you want exactly?

Comment: Generally speaking, operators in SQL are tristate... they return true, false and unknown. `NULL NOT LIKE 'A'` returns "unknown" instead of the _expected result_ "true".

Answer (score 1):

Use the `DISTINCT` predicate to skip A, but keep NULL:

```
select city, sum(counter)
from my_table
where city is distinct from 'A'
group by city
```

(ANSI/ISO SQL-2016 Feature T151, “DISTINCT predicate”.)